# if statement does not work in c#

Tags: c#

I have a fairly simple task which I want to do but something weird is happening. I just want to check if an element in a string equals zero and then set an integer accordingly.

This is my code

```
if (ssRow[(bar_position_row - 3)].Equals("0") && ssRow[(bar_position_row + 1)].Equals("0"))
   {
      back_row = 2;
      front_row = 2;
   }
else if (!ssRow[(bar_position_row - 3)].Equals("0") && !ssRow[(bar_position_row + 1)].Equals("0"))
   {
      back_row = 3;
      front_row = 1;
   }
else if (ssRow[(bar_position_row - 3)].Equals("0") && !ssRow[(bar_position_row + 1)].Equals("0"))
   {
      back_row = 2;
      front_row = 1;
   }
```

When I test my code, in several examples `ssRow[(bar_position_row - 3)] and ssRow[(bar_position_row + 1)]` equal zero but somehow the `ssRow[(bar_position_row - 3)].Equals("0")` and `ssRow[(bar_position_row + 1)].Equals("0")` are both FALSE. Does anyone know what my mistake is?

Comment: if your ssRow[(bar_position_row + 1)]  equals zero 0 then it should not be checked against a string "0" like you do. 0 is not "0"

Comment: For a complete question, post the exact C# declaration of `ssRow`

Comment: What is the value of `ssRow[(bar_position_row - 3)].GetType()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know the type of `ssRow`, if using index access on it does not return an `string`, then `Equals("0")` is doing object equality.

To fix it, consider using `.ToString()` first: `ssRow[(bar_position_row - 3)].ToString().Equals("0")`

Answer (score 3):

When you index into a string, what you get back is a [`char`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), not another `string`. You then compare this `char` to a `string` (`"0"`), and understandably get back `false`.

You should be comparing against `'0'` (a `char`), not `"0"` (a `string`). And since `char` is a value type, you can just use the `==` equality operator. If you had done so in the first place, this would have been a compile time error.

See example:

```
"abc"[0].Equals("a") //false
"abc"[0].Equals('a') //true

"abc"[0] == 'a' //true
"abc"[0] == "a" //compile-time error, can't compare char with string
```

Comment: Exactly, most likely the reason you get a false is that the types you are comparing are different, it's always handy to use the GetType() to verify that both sides of the comparison are the same before actually comparing the values inside if you are not sure they match